# opening a pdf in photoshop and then saving removes margins

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf

I wish to open a pdf in photoshop , remove some content and then resave it.  When i do this the new pdf has trimmed margins. What is the best approach to keep the margins the save as the original file. I appreciate indesign or other software would be a better for this job

Answer (score 5):

When you open a PDF with Photoshop you have a choice over what the bounding area is.

[image: Photoshop PDF window]

Simply choose the correct bounding area to retain your borders. Most often it will be the "Bleed Box" or "Media Box" if you want the full size.

Bounding Box and Art Box are generally the size of only the artwork in the PDF.

Trim Box and Crop Box will crop to the marks.

Bleed Box will crop to the bleed marks if there are any.

And Media Box will crop to the full size of the document, ignoring any internal marks.

Comment: In the context of this question: "trim size" would be the proper choice. "Trim size" is the trimmed/cut size, which the average person would call the paper size. [edit: yes, I am sure Scott is aware of this, I only comment in the interest of clarity. Presumably, the bounding box was smaller than the trim, indicating no bleed]

Comment: Yes. I've added to the answer. Thanks horatio.